# Calculo no R, valor do dado com a media e desvio padrão da coluna

Tags: r, tidyverse

O que tenho que fazer é simples: pegar o valor da célula, subtrair com a media dos valores da coluna, depois disso dividir com o desvio padrão dos valores da coluna.

Exemplo:

- Valor da célula = 2
- Valor da média da coluna = 1
- Desvio da coluna = 0,5
- Calculo = (2 - 1) / 0,5
- Calculo = 2

Fiz em forma de matriz, mas funciona apenas para primeira linha:

```
teste <- data.frame(ANO = c(2011, 2012),
                            C1 = c(1,2),
                            C2 = c(3,4))

> teste
   ANO C1 C2
1 2011  1  3
2 2012  2  4

for (linha in 1:nrow(teste)) {
  for (coluna in 2:ncol(teste)) {
    teste[linha, coluna] = (teste[linha, coluna] - mean(teste[ , coluna])) / sd(teste[ , coluna])
  }
}

> teste
   ANO         C1         C2
1 2011 -0.7071068 -0.7071068
2 2012  0.7071068  0.7071068
```

Acredito que tenta melhores formas de resolver isso com programação do R, e que traga valores corretos.

Answer (score 3):

### R base

É só aplicar a função base `scale` a cada uma das colunas.

```
res <- teste
res[-1] <- lapply(res[-1], scale)
res
#   ANO         C1         C2
#1 2011 -0.7071068 -0.7071068
#2 2012  0.7071068  0.7071068
```

---

### Pacote `dplyr`

```
teste %>% mutate(across(C1:C2, scale))
#   ANO         C1         C2
#1 2011 -0.7071068 -0.7071068
#2 2012  0.7071068  0.7071068
```

---

Em resposta ao [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/519072/calculo-no-r-valor-do-dado-com-a-media-e-desvio-padr%c3%a3o-da-coluna/519081?noredirect=1#comment947285_519081), em R base e com o pacote `dplyr`, em vez da função `scale` pode-se usar uma função anónima.

```
res[-1] <- lapply(res[-1], function(x) (x - mean(x))/sd(x))

teste %>% mutate(across(C1:C2, function(x) (x - mean(x))/sd(x)))
```

Comment: Se fosse pra utilizar a padronização que coloquei na formula ? Teria como ?

Comment: @DiegoWenceslau Pode definir uma função `f<-function(x) (x-mean(x)/sd(x)` e chamá-la tal como `scale` é chamada.

Comment: @DiegoWenceslau Ou com uma função anónima, veja a edição.